# PyWin32 image won't show

Tags: python, image, pywin32

So here is my problem, I try to create a PyWin32 application, everything work fine while adding a text and setting my window, but I can't draw a image. I don't know if I do something wrong or if my problem is elsewhere, so here is my chunk of code where I try to draw my icon image:

```
@EventHandler(WM_CREATE)
def OnCreate(self, message, wParam, lParam):
    self.hBitmap = LoadImage(0, self.imagePath, IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE)

    return 0

@EventHandler(WM_PAINT)
def OnPaint(self, message, wParam, lParam):

    hdcScreen = GetDC(0)

    hdcBitmap = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen)

    hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, 32, 32)
    hbmOld = SelectObject(hdcBitmap, hbm)

    gdi32.SetBkMode(hdcBitmap, TRANSPARENT)

    brush = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_MENU)


    FillRect(hdcBitmap, (0, 0, 32, 32), brush)

    DrawIconEx(hdcBitmap, 0, 0, self.hBitmap, 32, 32, 0, 0, DI_NORMAL)
    SelectObject(hdcBitmap, hbmOld)
    DeleteDC(hdcBitmap)

    return 0
```

If someone can help me with this and make it work, I will be really happy :)

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note: don't you have to call `BeginPaint` / `EndPaint` in `OnPaint`?